# AWS CLI Query - describe-keys with parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kms

So this week, I have started to begin learning the CLI and seeing what can be done within this.

I was given the task of grabbing information regarding this:

- Key Alias
- Key ID
- All associated tags

I have tried many methods within this... and can't seem to get anywhere. I have only been doing this for around 4 days and I just began documenting key API calls that will come in use for the future.

I seem to not be able to grab this in a --output table.

If anyone could be able to give me a guidance on this.

Also, does anyone have any tips from someone who is just starting his Cloud Journey and any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Please share pertinent code snippets and output.  [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to list all of your kms keys (KeyId and KeyArn Vaules) with the table format.

aws kms list-keys --query Keys[*].[KeyId,KeyArn] --output table